# Fortran PLplot: CALLing the subroutine PLsetopt results in a compiler Error

Tags: fortran, plplot

```
Ubuntu 20.04.1 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64
MATE 1.24.0
gfortran: GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
PLplot library version: 5.15.0

pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran :
 -I/usr/include/plplot \
 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/modules/plplot \
 -I/usr/include/plplot \
 -lplplotfortran
```

In my Fortran-Program (`USE PLplot`) there are `CALL`s to `PLgver`, `PLsdev`, `PLsfnam`, `PLsetopt`, `PLinit`, `PLsori`, `PLenv`, `PLlab`, `PLscolbg`, `PLcol0`, `PLcol1`, `PLfill` and `PLpoin`. Compiling the program with `gfortran test-plplot.f90 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran)` results in:

```
   24 | CALL PLsetopt ("-geometry","1280x720") ! ... generic 'plsetopt' at (1)
      |                                                                       1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘plsetopt’ at (1)
```

All the other `CALL`s to the PLplot-Subroutines work (which can be proved when commenting out the line with `PLsetopt`).

Answer (score 0):

The module `plplot` defines the generic name `plsetopt` to be a function, not a subroutine.

Change the invocation of the procedure from a call statement to a function reference of some sort.

Comment: _"The module plplot defines the generic name plsetopt to be a function, not a subroutine."_ - Ah, yes, I should have noticed this at e.g. http://plplot.sourceforge.net/docbook-manual/plplot-html-5.15.0/plsetopt.html .   _"Change the invocation of the procedure from a call statement to a function reference of some sort."_ - I changed to `PRINT *, 'PLsetopt (...) : ', PLsetopt (...)` and the compiler says: `Error: There is no specific function for the generic ‘plsetopt’ at (1)`

Comment: What specifically do you have for the `...`.  It works for me...

Comment: CALL PLsetopt ("geometry","1280x720")

Comment: That's still a call statement.  What do you specifically have when you invoke the function.

Comment: Sorry, copied from the wrong version of my program. So the code is - as mentioned above - `PRINT *, PLsetopt("-geometry","1280x720")`. Surprisingly (and luckily) now - contrary to a few days ago - there is no compiler error! So this problem is solved! But the output does not have the size 1280x720 but 1600x900, also when using `PLsetopt("geometry","1280x720")` without hyphen.